# Regex to find repeating consecutive characters in dataframe - python

Tags: python, regex

I have a csv with a name column.  I have been tasked with finding names that have a double-letter (two consecutive letters that are repeats).

I need to create a column in my Dataframe for TRUE if the name does contain double-letters, or FALSE if it does not.  I believe I have the regular expression necessary with ((\w)\2{1,}) but when I try to add this to the Dataframe the new column is empty.

```
df['repeat'] = df['Name'].str.findall('((\w)\2{1,})')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex you need is `r'(\w)\1'`: any alphanumeric character followed by the same character. If you want to match only letters, then use `r'([a-zA-Z])\1'`.

An even better approach is to call `match` because this method returns True/False rather than a list of matches:

```
df["Name"].str.match(r'.*(\w)\1')
```

Since `match` always starts matching at the beginning of a string, you must provide space for non-duplicates; `'.*'` takes care of them.